# In PHP , $mpdf->Output(); is not working in Paypal notification function

Tags: php

I want to make a PDF in paypal notification function even I also try to trace code with file_put_content but I can't get solution please help me for this.

```
function paypalNotificationdemo() {

    all other Code for paypal......................... 

    $this->Mpdf->init();

    $html = '

        <div style="text-align:center; margin-left:67%">
            Hello World
        </div> ';

     ..... OTHER HTML CODE FOR PDF ......... 

     include("../mpdf.php");
     $mpdf=new mPDF('','', 0, 'Calibri', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'L');
     $filename= "PDFNAME".".pdf";

     $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);

     // HERE THIS FILE PUT CONTENT IS WORKING
     file_put_contents("pdferror.txt",print_r(error_get_last(), true));

     // **BELOW LINE IS NOT WORKING IN PAYPAL NOTIFICATION BUT IN OTHER FUNCTION IT IS WORK PROPERLY**
     $mpdf->Output();

     // BUT HERE IT IS NOT WORKING  SO I CAN'T UNDERSTAND THE PROBLEM BECAUSE I CAN'T GET ANY ERROR AND I CAN'T TRACE CODE AFTER ABOVE $mpdf->Outout()
     file_put_contents("pdferror.txt",print_r(error_get_last(), true));

}
```

Comment: Check if 'mpdf.php' is included properly or not.

Comment: Thank for give feedback friend ... and Yes, It is properly included and also This code for pdf It is already working in other function but I want to implement that code in paypal nocification function so that in this paypal function it is not working specially $mpdf->Output(); this line which is create a pdf

Comment: Even I also try for other plugin html2pdf but same issue , it was work in other fucntion but not working in paypal notification function with same issue of obj->output() function